# DataGridView change row header color based on value in a column foreach row

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm programming a software for managing concurrent machines. The `DataGridView` shows status of the machine, I'd like to color red o green the row header of each machine if it's activated or not.

I've searched the web and tried multiple solutions, but no one of those has worked and headers are remaining grey, so I'm asking your help.

```
DGVMachinesStatus.DataSource = db.GetAllFrom("machines");
DGVMachinesStatus.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;

foreach (DataGridViewRow r in DGVMachinesStatus.Rows)
{
    if (r.Cells["status"].ToString().Equals(DBNull.Value.ToString()))
    {
        DataGridViewCellStyle rowStyle;
        rowStyle = r.HeaderCell.Style;
        rowStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        r.HeaderCell.Style = rowStyle;  
    }
    else
    {
        DataGridViewCellStyle rowStyle;
        rowStyle = r.HeaderCell.Style;
        rowStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        r.HeaderCell.Style = rowStyle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code working without any issues. Do you have any run time error?

Comment: Have you tried `EnableHeaderVisualStyles = False`? sometimes it is because of the default property not in your code. just check it :)

Comment: @Muj Please check the above code. It contains `EnableHeaderVisualStyles = False` already.

Comment: @Muj No need that. I have tested the above code. It works fine.

Comment: where or when are you calling this code ?

Comment: I'm calling it in the constructor of the form, I've no Runtime issues simply color doesn't appear on the Datagrid

Comment: I checked if condition again and it works, seems like the stye lines aren't working

Comment: I've found out code works out of the constructor, but i'd like to have the datagrid coloured when you open the form and it populates DGV

Comment: You could call the loading in the Form.Load event.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was caused by calling the code in form constructor, I avoid the problem using the activated event for colouring DGV when form is opened. I don't know if it's the best why but it works